# Fixing plots in Jupyter notebook when using %matplotlib notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am using %matplotlib notebook in Jupyter notebook however, most of my plots get cutout like the image below!
Could anyone help please so that the plots are generated in full view?

[Image I am trying to fit in full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVPJW.jpg)

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Before you plot, I assume you are using :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(some_dimension,some_dimension))
```

You can try reducing the figsize to make your graph fit

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.margins(*margins, x=None, y=None, tight=True)
```

*margins : float, optional
If a single positional argument is provided, it specifies both margins of the x-axis and y-axis limits. If two positional arguments are provided, they will be interpreted as xmargin, ymargin. If setting the margin on a single axis is desired, use the keyword arguments described below.

x, y : float, optional
Specific margin values for the x-axis and y-axis, respectively. These cannot be used with positional arguments, but can be used individually to alter on e.g., only the y-axis.

tight : bool or None, default is True
The tight parameter is passed to autoscale_view(), which is executed after a margin is changed; the default here is True, on the assumption that when margins are specified, no additional padding to match tick marks is usually desired. Set tight to None will preserve the previous setting.